# Blog, adding post doesn't work

Tags: php, html, post, pdo, blogs

So I made a blog with a function to add a post.

This is my code for adding a post

```
  <?php
include_once('resources/init.php');

if(isset($_POST['title'],$_POST['contents'])){

    $errors = array();

    $title      = trim($_POST['title']);
    $contents   = trim($_POST['contents']);

    if(empty($title)){
     $errors[] = 'You need to supply a title';
    }
    else if(strlen($title)>255){
     $errors[] = 'The title can not be longer than 255 characters';   
    }

    if(empty($contents)){
     $errors[] = 'You need to supply some text';   
    }


    if(empty($errors)){
        add_post($title,$contents,$_POST);



        header("Location:index.php?id={$id}");
        die();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Post</title>
        <style>
            label{display: block;}
            ul{list-style: none;}
            li{display: inline; margin-right: 20px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='index.php' >Index</a></li>
            <li><a href='add_post.php' >Add a Post</a></li>

            <!--li><a href='' ></a></li-->
        </ul>
     </nav>
     <h1>Rogier's blog</h1>
        <h2>Add a Post</h2>
        <?php
        if(isset($errors) && !empty($errors)){
            echo"<ul><li>",implode("</li><li>",$errors),"</li></ul>";
        }
        ?>
        <form action='' method='post'>
     <div>
        <label for='title'>Title</label>
         <input type='text' name='title' value='<?php if(isset($_POST['title'])) echo $_POST['title']; ?>' />
     </div>
     <div>
         <label for='contents'>Content</label>
         <textarea name='contents' cols=20 rows=10><?php if(isset($_POST['contents'])) echo $_POST['contents']; ?></textarea>
      </div>

     <p><input type='submit' value='Add Post' /></p>
     </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my index.php

```
 <?php
include_once('verwerk.php');
include_once('resources/init.php');
//$posts = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? get_posts($_GET['id']) : get_posts();
$posts = get_posts((isset($_GET['id']))? $_GET['id'] : null); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <style>
            ul{list-style: none;}
            li{display: inline; margin-right: 20px;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='index.php' >Index</a></li>
            <li><a href='add_post.php' >Add a Post</a></li>
            <!--li><a href='' ></a></li-->
        </ul>
     </nav>
     <h1>Rogier's blog</h1>

     <?php
     foreach($posts as $post){
      ?>
     <h2><a href='index.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>' ><?php echo $post['title']; ?></a></h2>
     <p>
        Posted on <?php echo date('d-m-y h:i:s',strtotime($post['date_posted'])); ?>
        In  AMP<?php echo $post['name']; ?></a>
     </p>
     <div><?php echo nl2br($post['contents']); ?></div>
     <menu>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='delete_post.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>' >Delete This Post</a></li>
            <li><a href='edit_post.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>' >Edit This Post</a></li>
        </ul>
     </menu>
     <?php   
     }
     ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the problem is when I click on add post it takes me to the add_post.php where I can write stuff down and add it, only problem is when I click on add post it takes me back to the index.php but my post is not shown.
Can someone help me fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the `$id` for the `header()` function in add_post.php? Check your url after adding post, to see if you are indeed missing the `$id` from the url.

Comment: Well, after adding the post the url is : http://localhost/Blog/index.php?id= , so I don't think I'm missing the id

Comment: To be sure, you should specify the `action` of your `<form>` tag to `add_post.php`. Not sure if you have URL rewrite enabled, which makes you forward back to index page.

Comment: @KimAllenboyNijenhuis If your URL looks like that, that means your `$id` is empty, otherwise it would look something like this "localhost/Blog/index.php?id=123". If `add_post($title,$contents,$_POST);` returns the ID, replace that with `$id = add_post($title,$contents,$_POST);`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was a bit busy with school, I tried what you say but it still isn't functioning. Thanks for your time tho